# Datagrid loop through the lines C#

Tags: c#, loops, select, datagridview, cell

I have the code, that randomly select row from datagrid. But I need to select not randomly, but step by step in the loop.
For example:

Row1

Row2 <- Selected

Row3

It must go in loop Row3 - Row1 - Row2 - Row3 - Row1 ...

If some one can help me with that, I will be very grateful to you.

Here is my code with random:

```
        Random rnd = new Random();
        int rowMax = dataSender.Rows.Count;
        int row = rnd.Next(0, rowMax);
        var arg = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, row);
        dataSender_CellClick(dataSender, arg);
        dataSender.CurrentCell = dataSender.Rows[row].Cells[0];
```

All what I want every time I use this code it got to move selected row to next row.

From Row2 to Row3. If there are only 3 rows, then from Row3 return to Row1

Comment: If you need to process all 3 items during the current loop, why don't you keep track of the row numbers you've used, so if it's selected again by the random call before the others have all be called, it will re-roll the random and try again

Comment: @Nick Scotney Hi, I dont want to use random select, I want to use step by step select row from X numbers of rows ... There can be 10 rows, or any other count of row.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is a little unclear, but if you're at say row 2, you then want to move to row 3?

If so, you could do something like this maybe:

```
Random rnd = new Random();
int rowMax = dataSender.Rows.Count;
int row = rnd.Next(0, rowMax);

for (int i = 0; i < rowMax; i++)
{
    var arg = new DataGridViewCellEventArgs(0, row);
    dataSender_CellClick(dataSender, arg);
    dataSender.CurrentCell = dataSender.Rows[row].Cells[0];

    row++;
    if (row == rowMax)
    {
        row = 0;
    }
}
```

So after your code finishes the dealing with the current row, you could increment the row integer by 1 and then check to see if it is equal to the maximum.  If it is, then you can set row = 1.

Again, if I've mis-interpreted I'm sorry, but in that case please could you make your question a little clearer

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I will try to be more clear.
I have for example 10 rows in dtagrid, at the moment are selected row number 8. All what I need, if some conditions, the row selected must change +1 ( it will be row 9 ), if there will be no rows left, it got to start from first row.

Comment: In which case, I've amended my answer to show the For loop approach as I believe this is what you need.

Comment: or `row = (row + 1) % rowMax;`

Comment: Thank you all guys, you all help me alot !!!